# Keeps calling itself when using the onClick event handler

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

***what I expect to happen:*** 
when the user clicks addProject button the event listener will run calling

```
formSubmit
```

and we will check for the date if it's valid or not then if it's valid it will call `fetchingCompanyNameAndUserData`

it will fetch the required data update the state and it will call `checkUniqueName` which again will fetch some data making sure there is no duplication and then it's supposed to call `this.insert()`
which will finally insert the data into our firestore-NoSQL- DB.
***The issue:***
these function specially the `checkUniqueName` keeps calling it self over and over and I don't know what is wrong there.
the code:

```js
formSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const isLoading = this.state;

  var sdate = this.state.projectData.sdate;
  var edate = this.state.projectData.edate;
  if (sdate > edate) {
    NotificationManager.error(`Please entre a valid dates`);
    return;
  } else {
    // isLoading = true;
    this.fetchingCompanyNameAndUserData();
  }  
};

fetchingCompanyNameAndUserData = async () => {
  const userRef = fireStore.collection('users');
  const userData = await userRef.where("Email", "==", auth.currentUser.email).get();
  userData.forEach(doc => {
    console.log('this one must match', doc.data().CompanyName)
    const cashedFirstName = doc.data().FirstName;
    const cashedLastName = doc.data().LastName;
    const fullName = cashedFirstName + ' ' + cashedLastName;
    return this.setState({
        companyName: doc.data().CompanyName,
        userName: fullName,
      }, () => {
        console.log('done fetching');
        this.checkUniqueName();
      });
  })
};

checkUniqueName = async () => {
  const projectName = this.state.projectData.title;
  const companyName = this.state.companyName;
  const projectRef = fireStore.collection('PROJECT')
  const projectData = await projectRef.where("ProjectName", "==", projectName).get();

  projectData.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.data().CompanyName !== companyName) {
      console.log('checking unique nameing');
      this.insert();
    } else {
      NotificationManager.error('this project already exists');
    }

  })
}

async insert() {
  //async function foo() {
  console.log('insreting proooo');
  var ptitle = this.state.projectData.title;
  var pdesc = this.state.projectData.desc;
  var sdate = this.state.projectData.sdate;
  var edate = this.state.projectData.edate;
  var status = this.state.projectData.status;
  var companyName = this.state.companyName;


  try {

    let response = await fireStore.collection("PROJECT").add(
      {
        ProjectName: ptitle,
        CompanyName: companyName,
        ProjectDescription: pdesc,
        startDate: sdate,
        EndDate: edate,
        Status: status,
        CreatedBy: auth.currentUser.email,
        CreatedDate: toUTCDateString(new Date()),
        LastModifiedBy: auth.currentUser.email,
        LastModifiedDate: toUTCDateString(new Date()),
        UserDocId: auth.currentUser.uid
      });

    let doc = await fireStore.collection("PROJECT").doc(response.id).get()

    this.handleClose();

    //alert(doc.id)
    var d1 = doc.id;
    this.props.history.push('/app/dashboard/addproject/' + d1);

    //this.handleClose;
    NotificationManager.success('Project Created Successfully!');

  }
  catch (error) {
    //console.log('error: ', error);
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Hope I made it as clear as possible here

Comment: There is a lot of commented-out code here.  Could you edit the question to show the minimal amount of code needed to understand the issue?

Comment: Thanks for fast responding, Done

Comment: Your call to `checkUniqueName()` is inside a `forEach` loop. Could that be why it "keeps calling it self over and over"?

Comment: actually that must be it, testing......

Comment: Also, when you say `checkUniqueName()` is calling itself over and over, is this because you can see the log message `"checking unique nameing"` multiple times? Because that is also in a for loop and will fire once for every document with the same project name (and especially if you have a problem with calling `insert()` multiple times, it will get exponentially worse on later runs because there will be more matches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkUniqueName()` function can be rewritten as:

```js
checkUniqueName = async () => {
  const projectName = this.state.projectData.title;
  const companyName = this.state.companyName;
  const projectRef = fireStore.collection('PROJECT')
  const qsMatchingProjects = await projectRef.where("ProjectName", "==", projectName).where("CompanyName", "==", companyName).get();

  if (qsMatchingProjects.empty) {
    this.insert();
  } else {
    NotificationManager.error('this project already exists');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for fast responding it worked eventually.

Comment: your code worked partially you have to replace the hasChildren() with projectData.exist because exist is a Boolean value attached to the querySnapShot we are getting

Comment: I've been working with the RTDB too much it seems. The equivalent code is [`QuerySnapshot#empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#empty). Because this is a query, you should be looking at the children of the returned snapshot, not the snapshot itself.